# Google Sheets Shifting Row Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I developed a website scraper to obtain calendar data and insert it into google sheets. However Some of the cells are in the wrong column due to having a missing time. For instance in the attached image in the Time column, there is GBP. What I'm trying to do is shift any row (starting at column M) that doesn't have a time value to the right by 1 cell so the GBP would move to currency, construction would move to Event and so on.

[image]

Here's the formula I'm working with. Unfortunately it shifts the rows that also has a time value. The rows with a time value should return as is since it fits within the correct columns and only the rows with text should shift to the right to position itself in the correct column. Does anyone know whats wrong with this formula?

```
=IF(AND(ISTEXT(M2),NOT(ISNUMBER(M2))),{L2,"",INDEX(M2:R2,1,1),INDEX(M2:R2,1,2),INDEX(M2:R2,1,3),INDEX(M2:R2,1,4),INDEX(M2:R2,1,5)},L2:R2)
```

Comment: Are you confident that time of day in M is actually time type?  I am used to date/time aligning to the rhs of the column, like numbers.  If it has been scraped and pasted into the cell, perhaps it has been pasted as text?   This would explain your problem, I believe, since your test clause AND(ISTEXT(M2),NOT(ISNUMBER(M2))). would always be true.

Comment: @DavidTew Yeah and when I change the format to time it spits out #value Error
An array value could not be found.

Comment: You could try substituting the following instead of your original test clause: ie. swap  
NOT(regexmatch(M2,"\d\d?:\d\d[amp]{2}"))
for AND(ISTEXT(M2),NOT(ISNUMBER(M2)))

Comment: that works when there is the text in the time column, but unfortunately when the M column has a time value, instead of displaying the original row it spits out value error due to there being numbers.

Comment: Oh, not what I expected!  It seems that it is a value after all.

My last attempt is to convert the time to text (within the formula, not on the sheet) using this as the test clause:  NOT(regexmatch(text(M2,"00:00"),"\d\d?:\d\d")))

Comment: yeah, still gives an error An array value could not be found. but thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(M1:M), L1:R1, {L1, "", INDEX(M1:R1, 1, 1), INDEX(M1:R1, 1, 2), INDEX(M1:R1, 1, 3), INDEX(M1:R1, 1, 4), INDEX(M1:R1, 1, 5)}))
```